# Can i make this code more efficient / shorter to run?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, wordle-game

So Im pretty new to javascript and coding in general. Im making a Wordle algorithm just for fun to build my skills in coding. and while making this algorithm i realized that i was going to have to kind of recreate Wordle. so i looked online for wordle recreations in java script, and all the ones I found I saw one flaw that I didn't want to have.

The flaw that I saw was in the IF statement for checking a letter in the wordle answer. Specifically when the letter is in the word but not in the right spot. The recreations that i saw had an IF statement that looked something like this.

```
IF (answerWord.includes(guessLetter[i])) {
        guessLetter[i] = color.(yellow)
}
```

(this isnt exactly how they wrote it, but its the main idea)

My main focus is on the `.includes`. This would not work because say our guess word is "agree" and the answer word "ready". the 2 E's in "agree" would be yellow, and we dont want that because their is is only 1 E in "ready. So we only want the first E in "agree" to be yellow and not the second E.

So i decided to figure it out on my own, and i was able to come up with this and it works. At least Im pretty sure it works, base on the the many words i tested it on.

So my question is, since Im making an algorithm im going to be making alot of calculations, is this the most efficient i could write this or can i make it better?

```js
let guessWord = "agree"; // the first word thats inputed
let answerWord = "ready"; // the answer to the wordle

/* 
  'letterCheck' is an array that tells what condition each letter in 'startLetter' is, based on the answer word
    2 = the letter is in the word and in the correct place (GREEN)
    1 = the letter is in the word but not in the correct place (YELLOW)
    0 = the letter in not in the word (GREY)
*/
var letterCheck = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
var guessLetter = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]; // the separated letters of 'startword' in a array
var answerLetter = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]; // the separated letters of 'answord' in a array

//adds the start word and the answer world to the arrays
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  guessLetter[i] = guessWord.substring(i, i + 1);
  answerLetter[i] = answerWord.substring(i, i + 1);
}

console.log(guessLetter);
console.log(letterCheck);
console.log(answerLetter);

//this loops goes though every letter one by one 
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  //checks if the letter is in the right spot
  if (guessLetter[i] == answerLetter[i]) {
    letterCheck[i] = "2";
    console.log(guessLetter[i]);
    console.log(letterCheck);
  } else if (answerWord.includes(guessLetter[i])) {
    //checks if there is more than one letter in start word or its the first letter
    if (guessWord.split(guessLetter[i]).length - 1 == 1 || i == 0) {
      letterCheck[i] = "1";
      console.log(guessLetter[i]);
      console.log(letterCheck);
      //checks if the the amount of same letters in start words is equel to the amount of same letters in answer word
    } else if (guessWord.split(guessLetter[i]).length - 1 == answerWord.split(guessLetter[i]).length - 1) {
      letterCheck[i] = "1";
      console.log(guessLetter[i]);
      console.log(letterCheck);
      //opposite of above
    } else if (guessWord.split(guessLetter[i]).length - 1 != answerWord.split(guessLetter[i]).length - 1) {
      letterCheck[i] = "1";
      console.log(guessLetter[i]);
      console.log(letterCheck);
      // checks if any of the letters infront of it are the same as it
      for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (guessLetter[i] == guessLetter[j]) {
          letterCheck[i] = "0";
          console.log(guessLetter[i]);
          console.log(letterCheck);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    letterCheck[i] = "0";
    console.log(guessLetter[i]);
    console.log(letterCheck);
  }
}
console.log(guessLetter);
console.log(letterCheck);
console.log(answerLetter);
```

( I will remove the `console.log`'s later they just helped my to debug.)

Sorry if my code might be confusing, im not the best at keeping my code clean. if you have any confusion or questions, I'll try my best in clear up any confusion.

Comment: _"(this isnt exactly how they wrote it, but its the main idea)"_: why not add the actual code to the question rather than be vague about it?

Comment: @Andy the reason i did this is because i found multiple wordle recreations that did the same thing with .include

Comment: Are you sure you want to create an array of characters from your words? Because a string can be indexed like an array just as it is. I mean instead of doing `guessLetter[i]` you can do `guessWord[i]`.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo yeah you're right, I guess I was just doing it to help me visualize it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all of the states (in precedence order: correct, wrong-position, incorrect), you should check in that precedence order, and remove letters from contention once the state in that letter's position has been set.

```js
function check(guess, targetWord) {
    const checkStates = new Array(5).fill("incorrect");
    const letters = guess.split('');
    const targetLetters = targetWord.split('');
    for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
      if (targetLetters[i] === letters[i]) {
        checkStates[i] = "correct";
        targetLetters[i] = '';
        letters[i] = '';
      }
    }
    for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
      if (!letters[i]) continue;
      let fi = targetLetters.findIndex(t => t===letters[i]);
      if (fi > -1) {
        checkStates[i] = "contains";
        targetLetters[fi] = '';
      }
    }
    return checkStates;
}

let solution = "ready"
console.log(`solution is ${solution}`);

let guess = "agree";
console.log(`checking ${guess}... ${check(guess, solution)}`);

guess = "roars";
console.log(`checking ${guess}... ${check(guess, solution)}`);

guess = "boars";
console.log(`checking ${guess}... ${check(guess, solution)}`);

solution = "beast"
console.log(`\nsolution is ${solution}`);

guess = "treat";
console.log(`checking ${guess}... ${check(guess, solution)}`);
```

Comment: oh wow thank you so much this is exactly what I need, I'm going to have to spend some time breaking the code down, so I understand exactly how it works. because I'm doing this as a learning experience. but thank you again.

Comment: I just wrote my own solution, which turns out very much in the same spirit as this one (although the code looks entirely different), when I realized that it's not right.  `check ('treat', 'beast') //=> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`.  But it should get `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]`.  I will try to look at fixing mine too, but I think we cannot progress sequentially until after we've already found the exact matches.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - I see your point. I've edited, adding the idea of two passes, first pass finds (and eliminates) the correct letters, the second find misplaced letters among those that remain.  It passes your new test, and I hope matches what wordle would do in any circumstance

Comment: @danh, without exhaustive testing, it looks right to me.  I may try to fix my solution tomorrow, if I find time.  It's much the same idea, but with code so different, it might be worth pursuing.  In any case, nice job!

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's something to consider in simplifying. You can use a simple MAP loop to determine which letters are incorrect, then later highlight those in the word.

```js
let guessWord = "agree"; // the first word thats inputed
let answerWord = "ready"; // the answer to the wordle

let tmpGuess = guessWord.split('');
let incorrects = answerWord.split('').map(e => {
  let i = tmpGuess.indexOf(e);
  if (i > -1) { // found it!
    tmpGuess.splice(i, 1); // remove
    return '';
  }
  return e;
}).filter(f => f);

console.log(incorrects);
```

Comment: thank you i think ill be able to use this in my code but think i would want `tmpGuess = answerWord.split('');` and `incorrects = guessWord.split('').map` but this does work thank you